# android http post base 64 string to .net wcf

Tags: android, wcf

This is urgent. I am trying to post an image convert to base 64 string. 
This is my Android (java) code.

```
private String decodeUTF8(byte[] bytes) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes,0);
}
   String json = "{\"Image\":\""+img+"\",\"Locationxy\": \"" + location
                +"\", \"PestInfo\": \"" + pestInfoTxt.getText().toString() + "\", \"UserID\":\"" 
                + user + "\" } " ;
```

At server, error: There was an error deserializing the object of type Pest. Encountered invalid character '
'.

How to encode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try passing in the `NO_WRAP` flag to the Base64 encoder. the JSON deserializer might be choking on unescaped newlines within the string.